# ffmpeg to merge mxf audio and m2v videos

Tags: merge, ffmpeg

Im new so not sure how to do this ffmpeg merge.

Im trying to merge a video and audio file together.

I have one video and two mxf audio.

i want to keep the quality if the video and map the sound onto the video

anyone know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this before. **What you need to do is this ->**

```
ffmpeg -i video.m2v -i audio1.mxf -i audio2.mxf-c copy output.mxf
```

Once you run the command, it will merge them together and give you an output.

**You can then run this command to match hmxf HDCAM formatting by doing this ->**

```
ffmpeg -i output.mxf -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:1 -c copy finished.mxf
```

`-map 0:0` for video `and -map 0:1` for audio

Comment: The first command will only merge one of the audio files. The 2nd will duplicate that audio stream.